# Systemd mount unit configuration *.img file on centos

Tags: systemd, systemd-unit

It is necessary to create a virtual file `samba.img` that will be a device and automatically mount it when the system starts.

creating a virtual disk from a file

```
fallocate -l 2G /root/img/samba.img
mkfs.ext4       /root/img/samba.img
```

craating mount point

```
sudo mkdir /srv/smb
```

I create a mount file to run at system startup

```
vim /etc/systemd/system/mnt-driveone.mount
```

mnt-driveone.mount contain

```
[Unit]
Description=Additional drive

[Mount]
What=/root/img/samba.img
Where=/srv/smb
Type=ext4
Options=defaults

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Next, add to autoload

```
systemctl enable mnt-driveone.mount
```

Run

```
 systemctl start mnt-driveone.mount
```

And I get an error

```
mnt-driveone.mount: Where= setting doesn't match unit name. Refusing.
```

I looked, such an error occurs when there are incorrect paths or spaces in writing paths, but my directory exists and there are no spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, the error tells you what's wrong!

Read `man systemd.mount` to learn about the unit file name requirements:

> Mount units must be named after the mount point directories they control.
>  Example: the mount point `/home/lennart` must be configured in a unit file `home-lennart.mount`. For details about the escaping logic used to convert a file system path to a unit name, see
> systemd.unit(5). Note that mount units cannot be templated, nor is possible to add multiple names to a mount unit by creating additional symlinks to it.

So your unit file must be named `srv-smb.mount`.